# starting docker backend from electron-vue frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, vue.js, electron

I am building an app based on electron vue. My electron app is supposed to start its backend running from a docker container. To do this I call a bash file with the docker run command in it.

```
    const {spawn} = require('child_process')
    const dckrrn = spawn('sh', dockercall)

    dckrrn.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
    })

    dckrrn.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
    })

    dckrrn.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`)
    })
```

Everything works fine in development mode but when I try it in my packaged app it complains:

```
stderr: pathtobashscript.sh line 13 docker: command not found.
```

It seems for some reason the spawned child process is unaware of the docker installation on the system. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to achieve this? Should I try the execfile function? Thanks for your time!

PS:
Sorry that I cannot provide you with a reproducible example, the total app with backend is around 7gb.

PPS:
some interesting sidenotes:

```
which docker
```

returns nothing, and:

```
pwd
```

returns: `/`

PPPS: I tried including the docker path at the beginning of my bash script but with no success:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin/docker:${PATH}"
```

export PATH

4PS:
I managed to get the docker running by adding shell: true to the environment. The problem I have now is that the docker folder mappings do not work anymore. So I guess I also have to make them visible to the env somehow.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')
const dckrrn = spawn('sh', dockercall, {
  env: {
    shell: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

solved by adding shell: true to the env:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')
const dckrrn = spawn('sh', dockercall, {
  env: {
    shell: true
  }
})
```